# Sub template is not rendering using backbone and underscore

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have two templates (Header and Details)

- Header contains some details and also on place holder for Details sections
- Details contain some more details.

**My problem is when i run application it will not replace Details template inside the placeholder of the Header.**

View 1

```
 var CalendarView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#header',
        model: todo,
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
            this.monthView = new MonthView({ el: "#dvDetail", model: this.model });
        },
        render: function () {
            template.render("testHeader.htm", $(this.el), { data: this.model.toJSON() });
        }
    });
```

View 2

```
var MonthView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        template.render("testDetail.htm", $(this.el), { data: this.model.toJSON() });
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

testHeader.htm

```
<div>This is header </div>
<div id="dvDetail">Sub template should be replace here...</div>
```

testDetail.htm

```
<div>This is details template and replaced on #dvDetail html</div>
```

When i run the application it will display

```
This is header
Sub template should be replace here...
```

**I would require**

```
This is header
This is details template and replaced on #dvDetail html
```

Can any body let me know what was missing in this code to get desired output? Any clue would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using underscore or lodash, this is my suggestion for your render functions ...

```
....

   template: _.template("testDetail.htm"), //just a sample , as an idea
   el: '#header',
   model: todo,
   initialize: function () {
       this.render();
       this.monthView = new MonthView({ el: "#dvDetail", model: this.model });
   },
   render: function() {
      this.$el.html(template);  //this will do the trick for you
   }

....
```

and same for your MonthView ...